# when database has multiple log files , which one SQL Server will pick?

Tags: sql-server

one of my database has multiple log files 
log.ldf - 40 GB ( on D: drive)
log2.ldf -70 GB  (on S: Drive)
log3.ldf -100 GB ( on L:Drive)

which log file SQL Server will pick first. is SQL server will follow any order to pick the log file ?Can we control this ?

Comment: Why do you want to control it?

Comment: i want to control the order of log pick, since the drive L has more free space, can i make log3 as a default log ?

Comment: And you think SQL will not figure that out?   You don't want a 'default' as you want it to use multiple.   It will figure out to stop using the small one (or any) when it is full.

Comment: See the answer from Slava.  Make no or slower growth on D and S.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't control into which file LOG info will be written.
You should not concentrate only on the **BIGGEST** file, but on the **FASTEST**

General advise would be to have ONLY two files:
- First file, as big as possible on the FASTEST drive (on SSD). Set MAXSIZE to the file size, so it won't grow anymore.
- Second file, as small as possible on big drive, where it can grow in case the first file is full.

Your task would be to monitor your second file size and if it starts to grow then make log backups more often and shrink that file back.

If you want to see how your log files are used, you can use following DBCC command:

```
DBCC LOGINFO ();
```